# Does the inequality hold?

Tags: inequality

I am trying to check if the following inequality holds true or not

$$\frac{1- \exp(-2st)}{2st} - \frac{1}{1 + 2st} \geq \left(\sqrt{\frac{1- \exp(-2st)}{st}} -\sqrt{ \frac{1}{1 + st}} \right)^2 $$

for $s>0$. I checked that $\frac{1- \exp(-2st)}{st} \geq \frac{1}{1 + st}$, but I am not able to check that if $\frac{1- \exp(-2st)}{2st} - \frac{1}{1 + 2st} \geq \frac{1- \exp(-2st)}{st}- \frac{1}{1 + st}$

Edit: $t>0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x=s t$. Expand the rhs and consider that you look for the zero of
$$f(x)=\text{lhs}-\text{rhs}=2\sqrt{\frac{1-e^{-2 x}}{x (x+1)}}+\frac{e^{-2 x}}{2 x}-\left(\frac{1}{2x}+\frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{1}{2 x+1}\right)$$ Making a Taylor expansion around $x=0$ gives
$$f(x)=\left(2 \sqrt{2}-3\right)+2\left(2- \sqrt{2}\right) x+O\left(x^2\right)$$  giving an estimate $$x_0=\frac{2-\sqrt{2}}{4} $$ Now, use Newton method for the following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.146447 \\
 1 & 0.244880 \\
 2 & 0.278281 \\
 3 & 0.281301 \\
 4 & 0.281323
\end{array}
\right)$$

So $f(x) > 0$ if $x >0.281324$

Answer (score 2):

It is not true in general:

Using simple calculus, one gets that as $st\rightarrow0+$, the lefthand side approaches $0$ while he right-handside approaches $(\sqrt{2}-1)^2$.

Here is a graph within the interval $st\in(0,0.5)$

[image]